# how to replace values in array with values from another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fetching an array:

```
$sql = SELECT id, name, state FROM table ORDER BY name
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = array();
$dict = ["A","B","C"];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//replace state value here before next line
  $rows[] =  $row;
}
```

Values in the **state** field can be 0,1,2. I want to replace the value in key=state of `$row` with the value from `$dict` so 0=>A, 1=>B, 2=>C. Value in state field equals position of $dict array. 
ex. if `$row=["id"=>"1","name"=>"john", "state"=>"1"]`
new `$row=["id"=>"1","name"=>"john", "state"=>"B"]`

Comment: You already have that exact mapping in your `$dict` array as key-value pairs. Coincidentally, but still...

Comment: I wounder why it's down voted ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like that:

```
$dict = array("A","B","C");
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $rows[$i]['id'] =  $row['id'];
   $rows[$i]['name'] =  $row['name'];
   $rows[$i]['state'] =  $dict[$value['state']];
   $i++;
}
```

If your `$dict` index is fixed into three index than it will work perfectly.

**Explanation:**

`$dict[$value['state']]` this will get the value as per index value.

Like if `$value['state'] == 1` than it will get the **"B"** from `$dict` array.

For the safe hand you can also use like that:

```
$rows[$i]['state'] =  (isset($dict[$value['state']]) ? $dict[$value['state']] : ''); // if not set than empty anything else that you want.
```

Comment: it's working fine for me, I just changed $value for $row.